# PHP: Convert HTML for use in alt/title attribute in a tag and keep the formatting

Tags: php

Essentially I have this

```
<p>hello</p>
<p>So I wanted just to say hi</p>
<p>I hope its going well</p>
```

Coming from a db.

If I just strip the tags then in the title I get this

```
title="helloSo I wanted just to say hiI hope its going well"
```

What I want (**like SO does it**).

```
title="Hello    
So I wanted just to say hi
I hope its going well"
```

I have tried using `\n or \r` and it just shows up in the title text.

```
title="Hello\n\rSo I wanted just to say hi\n\rI hope its going well"
```

Is this possible because of using **Markdown** and the way SO is saving the text?

I'm using TinyMCE and I have looked into ways of formatting the text, I've even tried using the output buffer to try and arrange the text how I want it.

Edit: Lets make this really clear and simple.  **It's going into a TITLE element!**

If I can't get this to work, I'll just do this via a popup with jQuery.

Any help / advise appreciated :)

Comment: Couldn't really understand your question. Please explain further.

Comment: When you say "keep the formating", do you mean to strip HTML tags and keep line feeds?

Comment: Take a look at the title tag for each question in the main page.  You'll see that it keeps the formatting of the text.  Use FF/Chrome tools.

Comment: @Alvaro.  Yes, notice originally I have <p> and then I don't..

Comment: Please note that what @PaulM wants is a very simple HTML to text rendered that inserts a line feed after each block level tag. Neither difficult nor trivial.

Comment: @Alvaro, you are welcome to the points if you answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, The string `'\r\n'` is interpreted just like that and consist of four letters. The string `"\r\n"` is interpreted as escape sequences and contains two characters, a carriage return and a linefeed. Use double quotes if you want to insert a line break in a string.

Comment: It's coming from the db as <p> I then change this to \n.  I then echo it out as $text.  So how can I use double quotes?

Comment: Alright, I have just tested outside of my website.  Looks like its something inherent with my single webpage application.  Groan...  Looks like I have to do a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, browsers won't render alt/title tags with multiple lines? It will simply remove the line spacing.

If they do now, then PHP requires you to wrap \r\n\t and other formatting in " double quotations as Sjoerd suggested.